# How do you tell whether sys.stdin.readline() is going to block?

Tags: python

How can I find out whether a call to sys.stdin.readline() (or, more generally, readline() on any file descriptor based file object) is going to block?

This comes up when I am writing a line-based text filter program in python;
that is, the program repeatedly reads a line of text from input, maybe transforms it, and then writes it to output.

I'd like to implement a reasonable output buffering strategy.
My criteria are:

1. It should be efficient when processing millions of
   lines in bulk-- mostly buffer the output, with occasional flushes.
2. It should never block on input while holding buffered output.

So, unbuffered output is no good, because it violates (1) (too many writes to the OS).
And line-buffered output is no good, because it still violates (1)
(it doesn't make sense to flush the output to the OS on each of a million lines in bulk).
And default-buffered output is no good, because it violates (2) (it will withhold output inappropriately if output is to a file or pipe).

I think a good solution, for most cases, would be:
"flush sys.stdout whenever (its buffer is full or) sys.stdin.readline() is about to block".
Can that be implemented?

(Note, I don't claim this strategy is perfect for *all* cases.  For example,
it's probably not ideal in cases where the program is cpu-bound; in that case it may be wise
to flush more often, to avoid withholding output while doing long computations.)

For definitiveness, let's say I'm implementing unix's "cat -n" program in python.

(Actually "cat -n" is smarter than line-at-a-time; that is, it knows how
to read and write part of a line before the full line has been read;
but, for this example, I'm going to implement it line-at-a-time anyway.)

## Line-buffered implementation

(well-behaved, but violates criterion (1), i.e. it's unreasonably slow since it flushes too much):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# cat-n.linebuffered.py
import sys
num_lines_read = 0
while True:
  line = sys.stdin.readline()
  if line == '': break
  num_lines_read += 1
  print("%d: %s" % (num_lines_read, line))
  sys.stdout.flush()
```

## Default-buffered implementation

(fast but violates criterion (2), i.e. unfriendly output withholding)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# cat-n.defaultbuffered.py
import sys
num_lines_read = 0
while True:
  line = sys.stdin.readline()
  if line == '': break
  num_lines_read += 1
  print("%d: %s" % (num_lines_read, line))
```

## Desired implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
num_lines_read = 0
while True:
  if sys_stdin_readline_is_about_to_block():  # <--- How do I implement this??
    sys.stdout.flush()
  line = sys.stdin.readline()
  if line == '': break
  num_lines_read += 1
  print("%d: %s" % (num_lines_read, line))
```

So the question is: is it possible to implement `sys_stdin_readline_is_about_to_block()`?

I'd like an answer that works in both python2 and python3.
I've looked into each of the following techniques, but nothing has panned out so far.

- Use `select([sys.stdin],[],[],0)` to find out whether reading from sys.stdin will block.  (This does not work when sys.stdin is a buffered file object, for at least one and possibly two reasons: (1) it will wrongly say "will not block" if a partial line is ready to read from the underlying input pipe, (2) it will wrongly say "will block" if sys.stdin's buffer contains a full input line but the underlying pipe is not ready for additional reading... I think).
- Non-blocking io, using `os.fdopen(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'r')` and `fcntl` with `O_NONBLOCK`
  (I could not get this to work with readline() in any python version:
  in python2.7, it loses input whenever a partial line comes in;
  in python3, it seems to be impossible to distinguish between "would block"
  and end-of-input. ??)
- [asyncio](https://cpython-test-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/asyncio-task.html) (It's not clear to me what of this is available in python2; and I don't think it works with sys.stdin; however, I'd still be interested in an answer that worked only when reading from a pipe returned from subprocess.Popen()).
- Create a thread to do the `readline()` loop and pass each line to the main
  program via a queue.Queue; then the main program can poll the queue before
  reading each line from it, and whenever it sees it's about to block, flush stdout first.
  (I tried this, and actually got it working, see below, but it's horribly slow, much slower than line buffering.)

## Threaded implementation:

Note that this doesn't strictly answer the question "how to tell whether sys.stdin.readline() is going to block", but it manages to implement the desired buffering strategy anyway.  It's too slow, though.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# cat-n.threaded.py
import queue
import sys
import threading
def iter_with_abouttoblock_cb(callable, sentinel, abouttoblock_cb, qsize=100):
  # child will send each item through q to parent.
  q = queue.Queue(qsize)
  def child_fun():
    for item in iter(callable, sentinel):
      q.put(item)
    q.put(sentinel)
  child = threading.Thread(target=child_fun)
  # The child thread normally runs until it sees the sentinel,
  # but we mark it daemon so that it won't prevent the parent
  # from exiting prematurely if it wants.
  child.daemon = True
  child.start()
  while True:
    try:
      item = q.get(block=False)
    except queue.Empty:
      # q is empty; call abouttoblock_cb before blocking
      abouttoblock_cb()
      item = q.get(block=True)
    if item == sentinel:
      break  # do *not* yield sentinel
    yield item
  child.join()

num_lines_read = 0
for line in iter_with_abouttoblock_cb(sys.stdin.readline,
                                      sentinel='',
                                      abouttoblock_cb=sys.stdout.flush):
  num_lines_read += 1
  sys.stdout.write("%d: %s" % (num_lines_read, line))
```

## Verifying buffering behavior:

The following commands (in bash on linux) show the expected buffering behavior: "defaultbuffered" buffers too aggressively, whereas "linebuffered" and "threaded" buffer just right.

(Note that the `| cat` at the end of the pipeline is to make python block-buffer instead of line-buffer by default.)

```
for which in defaultbuffered linebuffered threaded; do
  for python in python2.7 python3.5; do
    echo "$python cat-n.$which.py:"
      (echo z; echo -n a; sleep 1; echo b; sleep 1; echo -n c; sleep 1; echo d; echo x; echo y; echo z; sleep 1; echo -n e; sleep 1; echo f) | $python cat-n.$which.py | cat
  done
done
```

Output:

```
python2.7 cat-n.defaultbuffered.py:
[... pauses 5 seconds here. Bad! ...]
1: z
2: ab
3: cd
4: x
5: y
6: z
7: ef
python3.5 cat-n.defaultbuffered.py:
[same]
python2.7 cat-n.linebuffered.py:
1: z
[... pauses 1 second here, as expected ...]
2: ab
[... pauses 2 seconds here, as expected ...]
3: cd
4: x
5: y
6: z
[... pauses 2 seconds here, as expected ...]
6: ef
python3.5 cat-n.linebuffered.py:
[same]
python2.7 cat-n.threaded.py:
[same]
python3.5 cat-n.threaded.py:
[same]
```

## Timings:

(in bash on linux):

```
for which in defaultbuffered linebuffered threaded; do
  for python in python2.7 python3.5; do
    echo -n "$python cat-n.$which.py:  "
      timings=$(time (yes 01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789 | head -1000000 | $python cat-n.$which.py >| /tmp/REMOVE_ME) 2>&1)
      echo $timings
  done
done
/bin/rm /tmp/REMOVE_ME
```

Output:

```
python2.7 cat-n.defaultbuffered.py:  real 0m1.490s user 0m1.191s sys 0m0.386s
python3.5 cat-n.defaultbuffered.py:  real 0m1.633s user 0m1.007s sys 0m0.311s
python2.7 cat-n.linebuffered.py:  real 0m5.248s user 0m2.198s sys 0m2.704s
python3.5 cat-n.linebuffered.py:  real 0m6.462s user 0m3.038s sys 0m3.224s
python2.7 cat-n.threaded.py:  real 0m25.097s user 0m18.392s sys 0m16.483s
python3.5 cat-n.threaded.py:  real 0m12.655s user 0m11.722s sys 0m1.540s
```

To reiterate, I'd like a solution that never blocks while holding buffered output
(both "linebuffered" and "threaded" are good in this respect),
and that is also fast: that is, comparable in speed to "defaultbuffered".

Comment: I'm not certain you can _know without the possibility of error_ whether or not `stdin.readline()` is going to block.  For this reason, I don't know if your desired implementation is possible.

Answer (score 3):

You certainly can use `select`: this is what it’s for, and its performance is good for a small number of file descriptors.  You have to implement the line buffering/breaking yourself so you can detect whether there’s more input available after buffering (what turns out to be) a partial line.

You can do *all* the buffering yourself (which is reasonable, since `select` operates at the level of file descriptors), or you can set `stdin` to be non-blocking and use `file.read()` or `BufferedReader.read()` (depending on your Python version) to consume whatever is available.  You *must* use non-blocking input regardless of buffering if your input might be an Internet socket, since common implementations of `select` can spuriously indicate readable data from a socket.  (The Python 2 version raises `IOError` with `EAGAIN` in that case; the Python 3 version returns `None`.)

(`os.fdopen` doesn't help here, since it doesn't create a new file descriptor for `fcntl` to use.  On some systems, you *can* open `/dev/stdin` with `O_NONBLOCK`.)

A Python 2 implementation based on the default (buffered) `file.read()`:

```
import sys,os,select,fcntl,errno

fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdin.fileno(),fcntl.F_SETFL,os.O_NONBLOCK)

rfs=[sys.stdin.fileno()]
xfs=rfs+[sys.stdout.fileno()]

buf=""
lnum=0
timeout=None
rd=True
while rd:
  rl,_,xl=select.select(rfs,(),xfs,timeout)
  if xl: raise IOError          # "exception" occurred (TCP OOB data?)
  if rl:
    try: rd=sys.stdin.read()    # read whatever we have
    except IOError as e:        # spurious readiness?
      if e.errno!=errno.EAGAIN: raise # die on other errors
    else: buf+=rd
    nl0=0                       # previous newline
    while True:
      nl=buf.find('\n',nl0)
      if nl<0:
        buf=buf[nl0:]           # hold partial line for "processing"
        break
      lnum+=1
      print "%d: %s"%(lnum,buf[nl0:nl])
      timeout=0
      nl0=nl+1
  else:                         # no input yet
    sys.stdout.flush()
    timeout=None

if buf: sys.stdout.write("%d: %s"%(lnum+1,buf)) # write any partial last line
```

For just `cat -n`, we could write out partial lines as soon as we get them, but this holds on to them to represent processing the whole line at once.

On my (unimpressive) machine, your `yes` test takes "real 0m2.454s user 0m2.144s sys 0m0.504s".

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Regarding fdopen/fcnt for non-blocking i/o, I am using those correctly, i just typed it in wrong when i wrote up the question; I just now fixed it.  I think the problem I was running into there was I was still trying to use text mode and sys.stdin.readline() even with non-blocking i/o, and that simply doesn't work (in various ungraceful ways such as, in python3, returning "" when nothing to read, making it indistinguishable from end-of-file).

Comment: @DonHatch: I’ll be glad to edit the `fdopen` part, but first a question: why did you `fdopen` `stdin` at all?  It doesn’t even make a new file descriptor, let alone a new open file *description* that could support `O_NONBLOCK`.

Comment: You're right, my description of setting up O_NONBLOCK is still muddled. I did in fact try fdopen stdin.fileno() as well, but that wasn't to get non-blocking per se, it was to experiment with getting a file object with various different buffering modes... in particular buffering=0 (which in turn apparently required me to put it in non-text mode 'rb'... unfortunately intrusive, since I was hoping to not mess with the original readline() semantics).

Comment: @DonHatch: In Python&nbsp;3, at least, you can get the underlying unbuffered stream with `sys.stdin.buffer.raw`.  You can’t have unbuffered text streams because they might have to hold on to less than a character of bytes.

Comment: Your answer speaks in terms of "you can", but it sounds like "you must" since I see only one way through the maze, and it involves giving up readline(). To summarize:  "To tell whether reading will block, use select(...,timeout=0) on the file descriptor, which means you must implement buffering (including readline()) yourself, which means you'll need the input stream to be unbuffered, which in turn means it has to be binary (so if you want text mode you have to implement that yourself too); also since select can false-positive, you need to fcntl the fd to be nonblocking". Do I have that right?

Comment: If you'd like to present your clean implementation of "Desired implementation of cat -n" using the techniques you're thinking of, that would be most welcome. In particular, if my previous comment's characterization that there is "only one way through the maze" is incorrect (for example if you see how to make use of BufferedReader-- I don't see it) perhaps you could clarify by showing the various implementations you have in mind.

Answer (score -1):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
import select
import fcntl
import threading


class StdInput:
    def __init__(self):
        self.close_evt = threading.Event()

        fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdin.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdin.fileno(), fcntl.F_GETFL) | os.O_NONBLOCK);
        self.input = (sys.stdin.original_stdin if hasattr(sys.stdin, "original_stdin") else sys.stdin)
        self.epoll = select.epoll()
        self.epoll.register(sys.stdin.fileno(), select.EPOLLIN | select.EPOLLPRI | select.EPOLLERR | select.EPOLLHUP | select.EPOLLRDBAND)

    def read(self):
        while not self.close_evt.is_set():
            input_line = self.input.readline()
            # If the object is in non-blocking mode and no bytes are available, None is returned.
            if input_line is not None and len(input_line) > 0:
                break           
            print("Nothing yet...")
            evt_lst = self.epoll.poll(1.0)  # Timeout 1s
            print("Poll exited: event list size={}".format(len(evt_lst)))
            if len(evt_lst) > 0:
                assert len(evt_lst) == 1
                if (evt_lst[0][1] & (select.EPOLLERR | select.EPOLLHUP)) > 0:
                    raise Exception("Ooops!!!")
        return input_line


if __name__ == "__main__":
    i = StdInput()

    def alm_handle():
        i.close_evt.set()
    threading.Timer(4, alm_handle).start()

    print("Reading...")
    input_line = i.read()
    print("Read='{}'".format(input_line))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.